# SQL Server - select records from one table which are not in a subset of another table

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am trying to prepare a query to insert new entries in a daily report into a separate table in a SQL Server database.

I have two tables as follows:

**Table 1**

```
id   style_code   location_code
-------------------------------
 1   abcd         IST
 2   abcd         DEL
 3   wxyz         DEL
```

**Table 2**

```
id    style_code   location_code
--------------------------------
 1    abcd         IST
 2    wxyz         IST
 3    abcd         DEL
 4    wxyz         DEL
```

I want to select all the rows in Table 2 where the combination of 'style_code' and 'location_id' DO NOT exist in Table 1. In this particular example, that would mean returning row 2 from Table 2 as 'wxyx & IST' do not exist in Table 1. (There is no relationship between the id columns. Table 2 is a temporary table)

I have been trying to put a join into a Select query with NOT IN, but I cannot seem to get the query to work correctly.

```
SELECT *
FROM [Table 2]
WHERE style_code NOT IN (SELECT style_code
                         FROM [Table 1] 
                         INNER JOIN [Table 2] ON [Table 2].location_code = [Table 1].location_code);
```

I have a beginners understanding of SQL coding, but am no expert, and would appreciate any guidance.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `NOT EXISTS` and a correlated subquery.

```
SELECT *
       FROM [Table 2] t2
       WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT *
                                FROM [Table 1] t1
                                WHERE t1.style_code = t2.style_code
                                      AND t1.location_code = t2.location_code);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `NOT EXISTS`:

```
SELECT *
FROM [Table 2]
WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT1
                  FROM [Table 1] 
                  WHERE [Table 2].location_code = [Table 1].location_code AND
                        [Table 2].style_code = [Table 1].style_code
                 );
```

Some databases -- increasingly more and more of them -- do support multiple columns with `IN` and `NOT IN`.  However, SQL Server is not among them.

In addition, I strongly recommend using `NOT EXISTS` instead of `NOT IN` when using a subquery.  `NOT IN` does not behave intuitively if *any* of the values returned by the subquery are `NULL`.  In that case, `NOT IN` filters out *all* rows and the result set is empty.

Answer (score 0):

Alternate way - You can achieve this using a `LEFT OUTER JOIN`. This SQL may give you better performance than `NOT EXISTS` or `NOT IN` clauses.

```
select t2.id, t2.style_code, t2.location_code 
from table_2 t2 left outer join table_1 t1 
on t2.style_code = t1.style_code
and t2.location_code = t1.location_code
where t1.style_code is null;
```

Comment: I couldn't get this to work initially. I needed to change the  'where' to 'on' and the final 'and' to 'where'. At the moment the databases are too small to notice any performance differences from the 'NOT EXISTS', but intuitively this solution feels more robust. Many thanks.

Comment: Glad to hear that.  So it resolved the problem. Right? My bad ya i made a mistake in it. I just realized

Comment: Yes. Problem resolved. Appreciate your help! Now onto the next piece of weird SQL logic...